# How can I return all values as NSArray? from query in completion block

Tags: ios, swift

In QueryHK I run a HealthKit query for steps and the corresponding date.  I return the values in a completion handler.  In ViewController I declare the completion.  My problem is that the method only returns the last value from the iteration sample in samples.

- **Question:** I want **all** of the data returned in  the completion, not just the last value.. How can I return all the data from the query in an NSArray ?

**QueryHK.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

class QueryHK: NSObject {

var steps = Double()
var date = NSDate()

func performHKQuery (completion: (steps: Double, date: NSDate) -> Void){

    let healthKitManager = HealthKitManager.sharedInstance
    let stepsSample = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)
    let stepsUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()
    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(
        sampleType: stepsSample,
        predicate: nil,
        limit: 0,
        sortDescriptors: nil)
        {
            (sampleQuery, samples, error) in

            for sample in samples as [HKQuantitySample]
            {

                self.steps  = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(stepsUnit)
                self.date  = sample.startDate

            }
            // Calling the completion handler with the results here
            completion(steps: self.steps, date: self.date)
    }
    healthKitManager.healthStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)
}
}
```

**ViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var dt = NSDate()
        var stp = Double()

    var query = QueryHK()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        printStepsAndDate()
    }

    func printStepsAndDate() {
        query.performHKQuery() {
            (steps, date) in
            self.stp = steps
            self.dt = date
            println(self.stp)
            println(self.dt)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your completion handler receive an array of steps/date pairs:

```
completion: ([(steps: Double, date: NSDate)]) -> Void
```

(you could pass two arrays, one of steps and one of dates, but I feel like it’s clearer to pass an array of pairs since the two are tied together)

Then build an array of pairs of step counts and dates:

```
if let samples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] {

    let steps = samples.map { (sample: HKQuantitySample)->(steps: Double, date: NSDate) in
        let stepCount = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(stepsUnit)
        let date = sample.startDate
        return (steps: stepCount, date: date)
    }

    completion(steps)
}
```

If you want the query class to retain this information as well, make the member variable an array of the same type and store the result in that as well as pass it to the callback.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question based on your suggested changes to the QueryHK class

Comment: Thanks but you shouldn’t edit your question to make it a new different question, you should mark this one as answered (if it was) and ask a fresh question.

Comment: Hi, I am still struggling with this problem and I posted a related question yesterday.  Could you be so kind and have a look?     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214960/how-can-i-access-hk-query-result-from-the-vc